# the fixed value has been keep adding up

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code to let the data to be filled in my worksheet ("test").
r is the number represent how many set/row of data will be added in that sheet.
however, when I call the module, from the second time I refer to the "r". it adding up itself. 
how can I get the data from same set/row to be entered in the same row on worksheet?

```
Sub addVal(Ctrl As String, Col As Single, tRow As Single)
Dim ii As Single

ii = Me.packageNum.Value - 1 'my control name start from 0 to 9(max)
For i = 0 To ii
Worksheets("test").Cells(tRow, Col).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(StrConv(Me.controls(Ctrl & i).Text, vbProperCase))
tRow = tRow+ 1
Next
End Sub

Private Sub Confirm_Click()
Dim r As Single
Call addVal("lot", 4, fEmpty("test")) 'the fEmpty is another module to get the first empty row. working fine
r = 2 ' that was a variable number that get from another userform. now I just change to 2 for testing
Call addVal("estate", 8, r) 'r = 2
Call addVal("stage", 9, r) 'r = 4 (+2)
Call addVal("address", 5, r) 'r = 6 (+2 again)
Call addVal("suburb", 6, r) ' and so on
....... ' calling more same module
End Sub
```

Comment: You are using `r` only in `Confirm_Click()`? as from the above code I can't see anywhere that `r` becomes anymore then `r = 2`. So you must be adding it up in another part of your code before it goes back to the next call of `addVal()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `addVal`, you increment the third parameter `tRow`. Since you pass `r` as that parameter, it gets incremented. If you only want to pass the *value* of `r`, not the variable itself, use `ByVal`:

```
Sub addVal(Ctrl As String, Col As Single, ByVal tRow As Single)
```

Otherwise, `tRow` in the `addVal` function references the same memory location as `r` in `Confirm_Click` and changing one of them will change the other.

If you want to make sure that the reference to a variable is passed and not just the value, use `ByRef`. Here is an example:

```
Sub test()
    Dim x As Long, y As Long, z As Long
    x = 1
    y = 1
    z = 1
    MsgBox "x = " & x & "; y = " & y & "; z = " & z
    Call incrementValues(x, y, z)
    MsgBox "x = " & x & "; y = " & y & "; z = " & z
End Sub

Sub incrementValues(ByRef a As Long, ByVal b As Long, c As Long)
    a = a + 1
    b = b + 1
    c = c + 1
    MsgBox "a = " & a & "; b = " & b & "; c = " & c
End Sub
```

The last parameter is to see the default behavior.

If you google ByVal and ByRef you'll find more on that.

Comment: thank you, now it works. I didn't know that tRow will push the increment back to the reference. thank you again.